# Postgres not listening on its listen_addresses

Tags: postgresql

First of all, this seemed to work before a system restart. Perhaps the solution is some setting that wasn't persisted, the question is what.

In my `postgresql.conf`, I have `listen_addresses = 'localhost, 10.212.2.8'`

In my `pg_hba.conf`, I have

`host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256`

`host    all             all             10.212.2.0/24           scram-sha-256`

When I go into psql and run `show listen_addresses` I see this:

`localhost, 10.212.2.8`

When I run `netstat -nlt4 | grep 5432` only this comes up:

`tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN`

So somehow even though it lists both interfaces from the configs, there doesn't seem to be anything listening one of the interfaces.

What configuration might be missing?

Comment: See https://serverfault.com/questions/787426/postgresql-not-listening-on-local-eth1-after-reboot/788044#788044